# Install another language to Android keyboard

Tags: keyboard, languages

I have Lenovo a390 with goKeyboard by default, and I have tried installing Serbian Keyboard to it. I have downloaded it from Play store and nothing happens, but never mind.

Simple question is this: Is there a way to install new language to default Android keyboard? So I don't have this language in list of installed languages that I can choose from. I want to add a new language.

Is this possible? I would really like to avoid using third party keyboard, because this handset is very limited on resources.

Phone is rooted, so I can do lots of things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know that you don't want to install any third party apps but without which you cannot get the language you want.For Serbian try this [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.touchtype.swiftkey).

Visit this [page](http://swiftkey.com/en/keyboard/#what-is-swiftkey) to confirm the Language support.

" I would really like to avoid using third party keyboard, because this handset is very limited on resources." which according to me is due to the Less available memory on your device try to move your apps on the memory card(micro SD Card).

Comment: I have installed Touchpal x. It's almost the same

Answer (score 3):

If you mean the Google Keyboard, yes. Go to Settings > Language and input > Google Keyboard settings > Add-on dictionaries.

Refresh if you haven't done it for a while (or at all). Then just check the languages that you want. I don't know if Serbian is there though.

Comment: On my phone it says "Android keyboard" and there is no such option. Google keyboard isn't available in Serbia